# Helping with sed - remove specific lines with certain string

Tags: text-processing, sed

These are the contents of the text file:

```
cat
dog
elephant
cat lion
cat tiger
penguin
penguin emperor
zebra
```

I want to remove the line contain just *cat* and retain *cat lion* and *cat tiger* lines.

There could be *nth* number of spaces after the word *cat* in the *cat* line, it could be zero or 10.

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: So... do you know a regex for [whitespace](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)? Do you know a regex for [zero or more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)? Do you know about [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)? Put them together, and there's your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairy simple with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/^cat$/d' <file
```

`/^cat$/` only match line which contains only `cat`, then `d`elete that line.

or `awk`:

```
awk '!/^cat$/' <file
```

or `grep`:

```
grep -v '^cat$' <file
```